# Pandas Conditional Statement

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have used `Pandas` to clean/sort data and for stats/plotting. I have recently downloaded data for a year in this format:

```
Day | Event Start | Event End
```

And in another sheet propagated a year in 15 min. intervals

```
Day | Time
```

I need help with telling the program that if the dates match and the time is between the event start/end to print for instance 1, else 0 (for times an event is not happening).

I think this can be completed in an array but I am in need of some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Anything with `datetime` in pandas will require it to be set as [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Once it is in that format, you can do many things, including what you are looking, perhaps with [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) or [between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html)

Hope that helps!